# Trace Function Calls in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, stack-trace, abstract-syntax-tree, trace

I need to trace Function Calls based on called functions from a root file
It should show the function call sequence without including system functions 
What is the best approach for this problem 
What I have tried so far
Using AST to get function calls on root page and then opening all imports file and searching for function definition and repeating the process
Module Finder has been used to get path of modules for opening but it is not showing path of some files and some are in missing modules section

Is there any way to achieve this with or without executing the script
I have tried pycallgraph but it is showing the output in image format ,it's json implementation has not been done so I ruled it out

Please advice me on solving this problem and is there any other modules that helps to achieve this functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can set use the trace function with sys.settrace(). In principle, you can it on  every line of your code, but it also helps you  to check the function calls. Look at this link for examples.
http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2005/04/20/tracing_python_code.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly certain what kind of functions you want to trace or what metrics are you after , but for python code there is a builtin utility --  `-m trace`.

For example `min_exmp.py`:

```
def b(z):
    if z > 0:
        return b(z-1) + 2
    else:
        return 2

def x(a):
    v = a + a + b(a)*2
    print(v)

print(x(42))
```

We can run like this:

```
python3 -m trace --listfuncs min_exmp.py
```

Which produces:

```
256
None

functions called:
filename: min_exmp.py, modulename: min_exmp, funcname: <module>
filename: min_exmp.py, modulename: min_exmp, funcname: b
filename: min_exmp.py, modulename: min_exmp, funcname: x
```

You can read in greater detail here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/trace.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. It will only list which functions are called and does not produce a trace. [Here is an example.](https://paste.ee/p/qijSt)